# Throwing an error when Spring boot application tries to connect with mongodb atlas cluster

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-atlas

Spring boot application throwing exception while connecting to mongodb atlas

I'm trying to connect spring boot application with a mongodb cluster and I'm facing the following issue while starting the spring boot application.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDatabaseFactorySupport]: Factory method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' threw exception with message: Database name must not be empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:659) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:647) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:941) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:733) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:435) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1305) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1294) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at com.sandeepprabhakula.blog.BlogApplication.main(BlogApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDatabaseFactorySupport]: Factory method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' threw exception with message: Database name must not be empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Database name must not be empty
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:294) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDatabaseFactorySupport.<init>(MongoDatabaseFactorySupport.java:68) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory.<init>(SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory.java:75) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory.<init>(SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory.java:64) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.mongoDatabaseFactory(MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 20 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

this is the application .properties file

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://sandeepsandyo9o7o1:my_password@cluster0.fjfmmcp.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
    
spring.data.mongodb.database=blog
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Had the same problem too, you can also do this for a workaround:

Replace

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://sandeepsandyo9o7o1:my_password@cluster0.fjfmmcp.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
    
spring.data.mongodb.database=blog
```

with

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://sandeepsandyo9o7o1:my_password@cluster0.fjfmmcp.mongodb.net/blog?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

(put the database name before the question mark in the uri, in the application.properties)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Add this for workaround:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

@Autowired
Environment env;

@Override
protected String getDatabaseName() {
    return env.getProperty("spring.data.mongodb.database", "test");
}

@Override
public MongoClient mongoClient() {
    String uri = env.getProperty("spring.data.mongodb.uri", "mongodb://localhost/test");
    ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(uri);
    MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
        .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
        .build();
    
    return MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
}
```

}

Comment: instead of Environment you could also inject properties directly, just in my case i couldn't

Comment: Thankyou sir it's working.

What is the reason it is not working before.

Comment: It looks like its Atlas specific, seen same posts on their forum